# Symfony 2 - Secure Ajax Controller

Tags: ajax, symfony, authorization, access-control

I have ajax controler to store actions that are called through the `AJAX` from `JS`.

Here in every action I validate if request is made by `AJAX` and no other:

```
if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'You can access this only using Ajax!'), 400);
}
```

Now the problem is that not every ajax controller action should be called by everyone, but rather depending on a role of the logged in user.

The request to action is made by `AJAX` from `JS`, but since actions are in controller I am still able to get logged in user object by `$this->getUser()` and to check if user has acceptable `ROLE` to execute the controller action by `isGranted()`.

Example:

```
if (!$authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'This can be performed only by admin!'), 400);
}
```

Should I check `ROLES` from inside controller in every action or try to configure `access_control` for ajax routes in `security.yml`?

I have no idea what is the big difference between these two approaches, but would like to know which one would be more practical and could keep my ajax actions more secure.

Comment: As long as you write tests both of them will be equally secure. What I mean is, that the effect is going to be the same. 
If you would like to make your actions less verbose, you can use the yaml or you can use annotations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the number of `AJAX` Controllers you have. If you have so many controllers those are to be allowed only for a certain role, `access_control` in `security.yml` is a good choice. Else you can have the condition in each controller.

For dynamic permission layer, where permission to be decided based on subject attribute(the viewing content), You might want to use [voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).